# Move Wordpress blog to subfolder by another hosting company

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, a-records

I have a WordPress blog hosted on a Linux server by a hosting company. Currently it is living on a subdomain of the company's main site - a site I don't directly have access to.

We are trying to move it from the subdomain to a subdirectory. The main site is on a Microsoft server. The setup should look as follows:

- `www.mainsite.com` - Microsoft - Hosting Company A
- `www.mainsite.com/blog` - Linux - Hosting Company B

My problem is that when I change the site in WordPress from `blog.mainsite.com` to `www.mainsite.com/blog` I get all kinds of errors. When asking for support I keep getting pointed in different directions. Can anyone help?

Comment: I added some basic formatting to your question so it's easier to read. Please review [Stack Overflow's formatting documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) so you can do this yourself next time.

Comment: "I get all kinds of errors", okay, what are they?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot log into the old Wordpress install and change the site URL.

The correct way to do this is to:

1. Go to Hosting Company B and install Wordpress so you have a new, fresh install at www.mainsite.com/blog. Make sure you can access the "Hello World" generic wordpress install there
2. Go to blog.mainsite.com and install this plugin - https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/
3. **Export** your entire blog, media, etc with that plugin
4. Go to www.mainsite.com/blog and install same migration plugin
5. Follow plugin instruction to now **import** the .wpress file you exported in Step 3.
6. Optional: set up a redirect in .htaccess on blog.mainsite.com to point to www.mainsite.com/blog . You don't have to do this if you don't really care about SEO